# flutter refresh the user token of firebase in order to access firebase real-time database. (In a period of time)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I was using swift and Kotlin before.
We need to refresh the user token when we are using auth user of firebase to access firebase real-time database. (In a period of time)

How to do it in flutter?

Here with the code of Kotlin:

```
var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val cUser = mAuth?.currentUser
        if (cUser!=null) {
            cUser.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult> {
                override fun onComplete(task: Task<GetTokenResult>) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        val idToken = task.getResult().getToken()

                        println("token has been refresh")
                    } else {
                        // Handle error -> task.getException();
                        println("token refresh Error Error Error Error Error Error")
                        val textError = context.getString(R.string.errorForInsertDataToFirebase)
                        alertPopUp(context, "", textError)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: use this to connect to firebase real-time database - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database

Comment: Yes, I am using this plugin of firebase. Do you mean that if we use it, then we don't need to worried about the token issue?

Comment: Yes ! - Check Full e.g - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database#-example-tab-